# SQL How to compute a row value using collected SUM values

Tags: mysql, sql

mlb_pitchers table

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
| year | playerID  | nameLast  | IP  | ER  |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
| 1903 | mathech01 | Mathewson | 366 |  92 |
| 1903 | youngcy01 | Young     | 341 |  79 |
| 1904 | mathech01 | Mathewson | 367 |  83 |
| 1904 | walshed01 | Walsh     | 110 |  32 |
| 1904 | youngcy01 | Young     | 380 |  83 |
| 1905 | mathech01 | Mathewson | 338 |  48 |
| 1905 | walshed01 | Walsh     | 136 |  33 |
| 1905 | youngcy01 | Young     | 320 |  65 |
| 1906 | mathech01 | Mathewson | 266 |  88 |
| 1906 | walshed01 | Walsh     | 278 |  58 |
| 1906 | youngcy01 | Young     | 287 | 102 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

First thing was to get the sum of IP and ER for each pitcher who pitched from 1903 to 1906, but also had to pitch in 1903.

```
SELECT
  playerID,
  nameLast,
  SUM(IP),
  SUM(ER)
FROM mlb_pitchers
WHERE year >= 1903
AND year <= 1906
GROUP BY playerID,
         nameLast
HAVING SUM(CASE
  WHEN year = 1903 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END) > 0
```

Output

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
| playerID  | nameLast  | SUM(IP) | SUM(ER) |
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
| mathech01 | Mathewson |    1337 |     311 |
| youngcy01 | Young     |    1328 |     329 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

What I would like to do, and cannot figure out what to add to the SQL, is to add an output column (new row value) that uses the SUM values to compute the pitcher's ERA. ERA = ER / IP * 9. So the output should look like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
| playerID  | nameLast  | SUM(IP) | SUM(ER) | ERA  |
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
| mathech01 | Mathewson |    1337 |     311 | 2.09 |
| youngcy01 | Young     |    1328 |     329 | 2.23 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an extra output column that does the calculation for `ERA`, like so:

```
SELECT playerID, nameLast, SUM(IP), SUM(ER),  (SUM(ER) / SUM(IP)) * 9.0 as ERA
FROM mlb_pitchers 
WHERE year >= 1903 AND year <= 1906 
GROUP BY playerID, nameLast 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN year = 1903 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Comment: Perfect. Appreciate the quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT playerID, nameLast, SUM(IP), SUM(ER),
   9.0*SUM(ER)/Sum(IP) ERA,
FROM mlb_pitchers 
WHERE year >= 1903 AND year <= 1906 
GROUP BY playerID, nameLast 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN year = 1903 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```